# AWS Lambda: Unable to import module with Sequelize

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My AWS lambda function has been working great for ages.  I made a few changes today and deployed to my dev environment and got the following error in my Lambda cloudwatch log:

```
Unable to import module 'users/users_handler': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at VERSION (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js:14:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js:18:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.js:1:93)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

Any idea why this is happening?  My user_handler.js code isn't even mentioned in this stack trace.

Comment: I had a similar case, when I installed a package using npm in my local machine, I did not added --save, so it was not added to project package.json, so the package was on my local machine but  wasn't bundled on the zip uploaded to aws. (I use serverless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with Sequelize all of a sudden needing the "moment" package.  I'm not sure why, but if you look at this line of the stack trace:

```
at VERSION (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js:14:28)
```

And then open up that file in your project:

```
node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js
```

On line 14 you can see it's requiring moment. To fix this, install moment:

```
npm install moment --save
```

And then make sure it's being bundled with your package to S3.